# Any idea what was the final verdict in DS9

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In [Deep Space Nine](http://fr.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine), The whole serie is centered around "[The Prophets](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Prophet)". Through the show there are questions about what they are and what they can do.

At first, [Benjamin Sisko](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Benjamin_Sisko) (The Emissary) think of them as "*The wormhole aliens*". The more we go through the show the more we see that Sisko slowly change his vision about these Prophets.

I know it starts a little sooner then this but, in [Rapture](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Rapture_%28episode%29) (season 5, episod 10):

> Sisko uncover an ancient Bajoran artefact wich seemed to have "led"
>  him to it, latter in the episod, Sisko starts to have vision and he
>  literally embraces his role as The Emissary

In [the Reckoning](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Reckoning) (season 6, episod 21) :

> [Jake Sisko](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Jake_Sisko) and [Kira Neris](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Kira_Nerys) are being "possessed" by the
>  [Pah-Wraith](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Pah-wraith) (Sisko) and The Prophet (Kira).

In [Tears of The Prophets](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Tears_of_the_Prophets_(episode)) (Season 6, episode 26):

> Dukat comes across an ancient Bajoran artifact, he breaks it while
>  chanting a sort of incantation and then the spirit of a
>  Pah-Wraith enters him.

In [Image in the Sand](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Image_in_the_Sand_(episode)) (season 7, episode 1):

> Sisko learns that a Prophet came to earth in the exact purpose of
>  created him as the future Emissary.

There is a number of other examples but I think these 4 will suffice. After reading this (and knowing that these creatures live outside linear time):

Is there any final statement as exactly what these creatures are and (if so) what kind of technology are they using and again just how far their powers extend ?

Comment: thx for this usual point down ricky ;)

Comment: I don't think the question is sufficiently clear. We see in the show that they're *considered* as theistic beings by the Bajorans, but not by the Federation.

Comment: exactly why i state Sisko (A federation commander/captain) wich change view over the subject.... and thanks for letting me know your point of view

Comment: I don't think he ever expressed a change of view. He acknowledges their power and even transcends humanity to embrace his "prophet" heritage but I don't think at any point he would call himself a God.

Comment: If Sisko were to think of him as a God lol I would never have liked him the way I do... Emissary is far from a God

Comment: There you go Rick.. after reading your comment, seeing your usual point down and reading me back. I've edited this question. I hope that (for once) you'll find one of my post reaching up to your high taste

Comment: Dowqnvote changed to an upvote. Good question. Unfortunately the answer is "we don't know".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19713/discussion-between-rocket-and-richard).

Comment: to bad that does not show up before I hit the "Post your question" button

Comment: I assume you mean the duplicate? The system shows possible duplicates based on the title of your question. However, your question title is quite different from the duplicate.

Comment: yes i meant the duplicate :( i even tried different combination of tittle to be sure lol

Comment: “In Deep Space Nine, The whole series is centered around "The Prophets"”. I don’t think that’s quite accurate. It’s pretty much centered around the wormhole and the consequences of its discovery. The prophets become more involved in that towards the end, but they’re still kind of a side-show to the war that engulfs the Alpha Quadrant.

Answer (score 4):

The [Star Trek Encyclopedia](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Encyclopedia) (considered a fully canonical guide to the Star Trek universe) explicitly refers to the entities living within the wormhole as **alien beings**. It does note, however that the Bajorans view them as spiritual beings rather than mere aliens, a major plot point in [DS9 : In the Hands of the Prophets](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/In_the_Hands_of_the_Prophets_(episode)) :

> **Prophets** : *In the Bajoran religion, the Prophets are spiritual entities who provide wisdom and guidance to the Bajoran people.
>   Bajoran tradition holds that the Prophets were responsible for the
>   nine Orbs that served as sources of wisdom for the people of Bajor.
>   **Many Bajorans believe that the alien beings first encountered in the Bajoran wormhole by Commands Benjamin Sisko in 2369 were in fact the
>   Prophets** These life-forms found the concept of linear time to be
>   totally alien, and Sisko attempted to help them understand the
>   importance of linear existence to Bajorans and humans. Ironically,
>   although Sisko did not believe in the Bajoran religion...*

As to their technology, it's not clear that their powers have any technological basis. Like the Q, Nagilum and various other energy beings, their abilities seem to be biological rather than technological. We can actually see this process occurring in [TNG : Transfigurations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfigurations) where a physical being attains an energy state.

Comment: Yup all I've read on http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Portal:Main ... and this episod is in season 1 wich dont really match with my question wich is after all the event (like my example wich the last one is in season 7) .. so i would like an answer or some fact after the event in the fire caves in the series finale

Comment: thx for this and i had to edit back my question when i read your edited answer